# how to create uicollectionview with swift programatically (without storyboard)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

i am trying to create a uicollectionview with swift programmatically, without any storyboard. and i need it to be multiple uicollectionview. 
this is my code

```
class jobtypeViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource{
var collectionview1 = UICollectionView()
var collectionview2 = UICollectionView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)

    collectionview1 = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    self.collectionview1.delegate = self
    self.collectionview1.dataSource = self
    collectionview1.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    self.view.addSubview(collectionview1)

    collectionview2 = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    self.collectionview2.delegate = self
    self.collectionview2.dataSource = self
    collectionview2.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    self.view.addSubview(collectionview2)
```

}

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if collectionView == self.collectionview1 {
        return 5
    }else{
        return 4
    }
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if collectionView == self.collectionview1 {
        let cellA = collectionview1.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell",forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
        return cellA
    }

    else {
        let cellB = collectionview2.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
        return cellB
    }
}
```

}

everything seem fine i have the layout,delegate,and datasource, but when i run it i got this message error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'. did i miss something??

Comment: i forgot to add that i create a storyboard for this, but i want to make the uicollectionview from pure coding (no collectionview in storyboard). i do not know if it make differences. cause i can still make it with segmentcontrol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initializers look correct, however, your member variables are initialized with an empty initializer which will be evaluated before viewDidLoad is triggered

```
 var collectionview1 = UICollectionView()
```

You can change it to be implicitly unwrapped since you're initializing these values right away in your viewDidLoad

```
var collectionview1: UICollectionView!
```

Comment: now everything are red lol. i got error from it "expected member name or constructor call after type name".

Comment: are you sure you changed your properties to the syntax I provided ? From the error, it does not sound like it. Note the colon instead of the assignment operator(=)

Comment: lol silly me, it didnt give me error now but when i go to the viewcontroller the whole thing turn black.

Comment: could be a lot of reasons, setting the backgroundColor of the collection view or collection view cells to white or whatever you want it to. Note you're also adding collection view on top of another collection view since they have the same exact frame. Time to debug and learn, good luck!